# how to set extraEnv in helm install command for airflow helm chart using the --set keyword?

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

if I run `helm show values apache-airflow/airflow | grep extraEnv: -A 2`
it returns

```
extraEnv: ~
# eg:
# extraEnv: |
#   - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES
#     value: 'True'
```

I want to pass

```
extraEnv: |
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES
    value: 'True'
```

to the chart install command but do not want to create custom values.yaml file and use -f flag

I just want to simply use --set flag. How to do that?

Comment: The value of `extraEnv` is a multi-line string that happens to be a YAML fragment.  How would you pass the multi-line string as a command-line argument (not Helm specific, just in general)?  You might find the `helm install -f` option easier to use here.

Comment: @DavidMaze how would you do that?